# What do the colors of completed words mean?

Tags: word-hero

Most of the time when I complete a word, it is grey in the list.  Every so often, it is green, red, or yellow.  What do these colors mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to:

Help > Learn to Play > Word Colors

Then it details some different colours that are used for certain words (although it does state these are used on the results screen, I would assume the app is consistent in highlighting words). This is as follows:

> - Red = theme words (always highlighted)
> - Green = common words you found (where common = used in 90% of english language)
> - Blue = uncommon words you found

There is no suggestion of yellow, although when highlighting a word it will flash yellow by default if you have already found that word. And I can only assume a grey colour indicates the word does not fall into any of the other criteria.